# SharePoint Column Replication

Tags: sharepoint-designer

When importing an Excel file several columns are duplicated such as 'Title', 'Category', 'Created', etc.  Can I control when these SharePoint generated columns are created or not?

Answer (score 0):

When we create a Custom List in SharePoint site, by default 5 columns are added to custom list and they are as follows,

1.Title (Single line of text) - Mandatory field that defines a title for each list item.

2.Created (Date and Time) -  When the user has created the current item.

3.Modified (Date and Time) - When the last user has modified the current item.

4.Created By (Person or Group) - User who created the current item.

5.Modified By (Person or Group) - User who last modified the current item.

We can modify the column properties by clicking on Column Name from List Settings.

Hope this helps you.